# Multiplicative Inverse of Polynomials in Finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, polynomials, ring-theory

Find the multiplicative inverse of $x + 2$ in the field $\Bbb Z_5[x]/(x^2 + 2)$.

I have done the following so far:

\begin{align*} x^2+2 &= (x+2)(x+3) + 1\\
(x+2)(x+3) &\equiv -1 \pmod {x^2+2}\\
(x+2)(x+3) &\equiv 4 \pmod {x^2+2},
\end{align*}

therefore multiplying both sides by $4,$

$$4(x+2)(x+3) \equiv 1 \pmod {x^2+2}.$$

This is as far as i can get to figuring it out.

Now I have the final answer and it states that:
inverse of $(x+2) = 4(x+3) = 4x+2$???
Can someone please explain to me how the answers are able to go from where i have finished to this final solution?

Thank you

Comment: You were finished. By your calculation, $[x+2][4(x+3)]\equiv 1\pmod{x^2+2}$.  So $4x+2$ is the inverse of $x+2$.

Comment: I think it would be more expressive to write the elements of $\mathbf F_5$ as $0,\pm 1,\pm2$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, can you please explain it in a little more detail as to how 4x+2 is the inverse, considering initially i have [x+2][4(x+3)]. How is the 4 not related to (x+2) initially?

Comment: I do not know what the issue is. In arithmetic mod $5$, we have $4(x+3)=4x+2$ since $4\cdot 3=2$. Or is the uncertainty somewhere else?

Comment: Sorry there is some uncertainty elsewhere, i may not have not explained myself properly. 
When i multiply both sides by 4 to result in 4((x+2)(x+3)) how does that lead to what your responded with of only multiply (x+3) by 4. [x+2][4(x+3)]?